# O que é a Interface endpoint no EJB?

Tags: java, java-ee, interface, ejb

Estou estudando EJB(Enterprise Java Beans) e gostaria de saber, dentro do contexto de aplicações distribuídas, qual o papel da interface endpoint.

- O que é a interface endpoint?
- Onde e quando a interface deve ser usada?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Uma interface endpoint é um recurso utilizado em um webservice para identificar a localização de uma interface. Em Português claro, o endpoint é o endereço em que uma interface está exposta e possui o formato de uma URL, por exemplo `http://localhost:8080/AquiEstaMeuServico`. Aqui considero como interface um conjunto de métodos implementados com EJBs. O endereço endpoint é usado em aplicações clientes que desejam consumir os serviços expostos. A maioria das APIs para webservices (eg JAX-WS, Axis) requer o endpoint/endereço para enviar uma requisição utilizando um certo protocolo, como SOAP, por exemplo. Esse é um recurso muito utilizado em aplicações empresariais distribuídas que demandam alta integração de sistemas.